# Merging images in JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing

I was trying to build a tinder clone project by using Java Swing. What I am trying to do is that when I clicked on people's images in the JPanel where I'd added people who were matched with the logged user, I wanna display an **X** icon which is gonna delete the user from my database and JTable when it's clicked on.

My JTable looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z8J5.png]

I've tried to approach from multiple aspects but I could not certainly figure out what to do. How am I gonna create a new Label which is the **X** icon under the clicked picture in the JPanel?

My code while adding matched people's pictures to the JPanel:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id_liked from tinder.likes where id_user = " + Login.loggedUser.id);
    
    while (rs.next()) {
        
        ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select id_liked from tinder.likes where id_user = " + rs.getInt(1));
        
        while (rs2.next()) {
            
            if(rs2.getInt(1) == Login.loggedUser.id) {
                System.out.println("if'in içi");
                
                ResultSet rs3 = st3.executeQuery("select id, name from tinder.users where id = " + rs.getInt(1));
                rs3.next();
                
                JLabel person = new JLabel(rs3.getString(2));
                person.setIcon(new ImageIcon(conn.getPhoto(rs3.getInt(1)).getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                person.setToolTipText(rs3.getInt(1) + "");
                person.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Light", Font.BOLD, 11));
                person.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                person.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                person.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
                        person.setBorder(border);
                    }
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        person.setBorder(null);
                    }
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(person.getToolTipText());
                    }
                });
                panel.add(person);
             
                break;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't combine `JLabels`.  You take the `BufferedImage` of the person and using `Graphics` methods, draw a red X on the `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Instead of adding a Label  (`panel.add(person)`) add a `JPanel`. Add the `person` as well as a `Jbutton("x")` to that `JPanel`.